# Creating two Co-dependant <select> elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Note, This question is *definitely not about cascading select*. That I know how to do. Please read before marking as duplicate you will see this is not a cascade it is co-dependence.

I'm writing a form that includes filtering search results by year. I have used two dropdown (select) boxes for this with ids "from" and "to". The "logic" of the application will obviously require that the "to" value is >= the "from" value. I would like this to be reflected in the presentation layer. Namely, if I selected "1998" in the "from" dropdown then I should only be allowed to select options greater than this in the "to" dropdown, *and visa versa*.

I've implemented a *minimal* example for this which appears below. This solution works well if the user chooses a "from" option, then a "to" option, and then moves on. However, if the user keeps changing back and forth then problems will start appearing. The reason for this is that I'm re-setting the HTML of all the options for a select whenever the other select changes. But this has the effect of also resetting the "default".

So, for example, if I pick "3" in "from" (in example below), then pick "5" in "to", and then go  back and pick "2" in "from", the the "to" box resets to "2", even though "5" was a valid choice.

My question is, is there a better way to do this than by using ".innerHTML" and resetting the whole options list? Or do I just have to manually put the default back to what it was if it is still valid?

I hope this is somewhat clear. Am new to frontend, apologies. Code below:

```js
function updateTo(e) {
  var to = document.getElementById("to");
  update(to, e.value, 6);
}

function updateFrom(e) {
  var from = document.getElementById("from");
  update(from, 1, e.value);
}

function update(elmnt, beginValue, endValue) {
  selections = ""
  for (var i = beginValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    selections += "<option>" + i.toString() + "</option>";
    elmnt.innerHTML = selections;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>FROM:</h3>
<select id="from" onchange="updateTo(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>


<h3>TO:</h3>
<select id="to" onchange="updateFrom(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cascading select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901061/cascading-select)

Comment: besides, there are blatant errors in the above markup ...

Comment: I do not think that this is a cascading scenario. It's a co-dependant scenario, and this problem id distinctly related to that. That's why I asked a new question...

Comment: What errors?? It runs fine

Comment: don't tell me this is valid HTML.

Comment: This is valid HTML

Comment: Seriously though, non-complience with standards does not about to a blatant error by any reasonable definition thereof. I had more boilerplate in the first version and a moderator suggested the edit to keep it more minimal, which makes total sense since IT DOES RUN and clearly illustrates the problem. Stop trolling.

Comment: Yes you need to reset value or selected if you replace all the `<option>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet - the code speaks for itself:

```js
// re-write the options
const updateOptionElements = (elt, low, high, selected = null) => {
  elt.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i=low; i<high; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = ''+i;
    if (i==selected) option.setAttribute('selected', 'true');
    elt.appendChild(option);
  }
}

// initialize DOM selectors and variables value bindings
const to = document.querySelector('#to');
const from = document.querySelector('#from');
let toSelected = 0;
let fromSelected = 9;

// initializes options
updateOptionElements(to, 0, 10, toSelected);
updateOptionElements(from, 0, 10, fromSelected);

// add change listeners to update the options upon change
to.onchange = evt => {
  toSelected = +evt.target.value;
  updateOptionElements(from, toSelected+1, 10, fromSelected);
}
from.onchange = evt => {
  fromSelected = +evt.target.value;
  updateOptionElements(to, 0, fromSelected, toSelected);
}
```

```html
<select id="to"></select>
<select id="from"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

just set the previously selected value to temp variable (`value`) and sets it again to the select after `innerHTML`

```js
function updateTo(e) {
  var to = document.getElementById("to");
  var value = to.value;
  update(to, e.value, 6);
  to.value = value < e.value ? e.value : value;
}

function updateFrom(e) {
  var from = document.getElementById("from");
  var value = from.value;
  update(from, 1, e.value);
  from.value = value;
}

function update(elmnt, beginValue, endValue) {
  selections = ""
  for (var i = beginValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    selections += "<option>" + i.toString() + "</option>";
  }
  elmnt.innerHTML = selections;
}
```

```html
<h3>FROM:</h3>
<select id="from" onchange="updateTo(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>


<h3>TO:</h3>
<select id="to" onchange="updateFrom(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Aswin for you answer. Both this answer and the one by Nino are, I think, sufficient answers. I'm going to accept his because it was first, but upvoted yours.

Comment: @Neil Thank you, that's so nice of you